# Apache 1 vs Apache 2 for serving download

Tags: apache-2.2

Which is good for serving download in windows (w/o php and stuff)?

Apache 1

Apache 2

Win lighttpd

I consider this because some files contain unicode chars too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I consider this because some files
>   contain unicode chars too.

This doesn't matter. Files are just a bag of bits and bytes for the webserver - and if they are not, the webserver is broken by design.

For serving static files, I'd use a very lightweight webserver like lighttpd, nginx or gatling. Apache httpd 1.3/2.x could of course accomplish the same goal but it usually has a heavier memory footprint than one of the lightweight webservers.

Comment: Things might be more complicated if the files have unicode characters in their names rather than just in their content. But I agree that lighttpd or nginx (or similar) would be a better choice than Apache (or IIS) for static files. As the questioner is using Windows, sticking with IIS would be preferable to getting Apache going for the little benefit they might possibly see.